# AWS Elastic Beanstalk: Not able to configure custom logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am new to AWS elastic beanstalk and trying to stream my application log file to Cloudwatch logs using configuration file (.ebextensions.)

I'm reusing the same configuration code provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44052421/aws-elastic-beanstalk-add-custom-logs-to-cloudwatch/)

I have placed the `mycustom.conf` in .ebextensions folder and placed this folder in ROOT of my .war file. 
I validated the YAML code using online validator (http://www.yamllint.com/) and no issues were reported. 
I haven't seen any error in either eb-activity-log or eb-publish-logs.
I also tried doing ssh to my instance and I couldn't find the file `mycustom.conf` created in `/etc/awslogs/config/`. Is there anything that am missing ?

Adding `mycustom.conf` below: 
Please help!!

```
files:
  "/etc/awslogs/config/mycustom.conf" :
    mode: "000600"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      [/var/log/tomcat8/myapp.log]
      log_group_name = `{"Fn::Join":["/", ["/aws/elasticbeanstalk", { "Fn::Select" : [ "1", { "Fn::Split" : [ "-", { "Ref":"AWSEBEnvironmentName" } ] } ] }, "var/log/tomcat8/myapp.log"]]}`
      log_stream_name = `{"Fn::Join":["--", [{ "Ref":"AWSEBEnvironmentName" }, "{instance_id}"]]}`
      file = /var/log/tomcat8/myapp.log*
```

Comment: Did you allow your EC2 instances to access Cloudwatch?  You will need to add the CloudWatchAgentServerPolicy and possibly AmazonEC2RoleforSSM policies to your aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role.  [Here is some documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/installing-cloudwatch-agent-ssm.html) (though it looks like the SSM policy may be called AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore now)