# How to get logs from elastic bean stack to cloud watch?

Tags: iis, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch

We need to get logs from elastic bean stack to cloud watch, we need to get logs IIS logs from EC2 server and some one told me to get logs from IIS logs from EC2 server to cloud watch is not same process like getting logs from EC2 server through cloud watch agent, please help me if its not same process like EC2 how to do it?

i tried to get logs from EC@ server but I've been told getting from elastic bean stack is different and it wont work like how it works with EC2

Answer (score 0):

I have not got it working - but found some help here:
[AWS Elastic Beanstalk: Add custom logs to CloudWatch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44052421/aws-elastic-beanstalk-add-custom-logs-to-cloudwatch)

And here:
https://aws.plainenglish.io/how-to-setup-aws-elasticbeanstalk-to-stream-your-custom-application-logs-to-cloudwatch-d5c877eaa242